# How to use text box to search listbox wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, search, listbox

I have a list directly assigned to a list box. I want to use a text box and a button to search the contents of the list box, so after typing in a word, when the user presses the button it displays it in the listbox of all the entries. E.g. if I type apple and press enter the listbox should show entries of the word contains apple.

I have assigned the list to the listbox using:

```
Messages.ItemSource = messages;
```

So far I have

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

But I don’t know what to put inside the button

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are going to want to iterate through the entries of the messages which is what you set your ItemSource to and check each entry against the current message. You can accomplish this by using the Linq Where method. Then once you have picked out all the messages that contain the chosen word, you can set your ItemSource to the list of found words. Here is a sample.

```
public List<string> messages = new List<string>() { "Apple", "Apple Pie", "Apple Jam", "Orange", "Banana" };

public void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var foundList = messages.Where(m => m.Contains(textBox.Text)).ToList();        
    Messages.ItemsSource = foundList;
}
```

I don't have access to visual studio right now, so I have not tested that, but it should be something like that. And you should be able to actually add that code to the TextBoxChanged event so that it updates while you are typing.

Comment: I have an error under Select. It says Listbox does not contain a definition for Select

Comment: You need to use Linq. at the top in the using directives use: using System.Linq. Also you are not doing this on a listbox. You are using Select on the List that you set the itemsource to.

Comment: Sorry had to update my code. I used Select instead of Where.

Comment: The .Contains doesn’t appear? I’ve used m.Equals instead but when I type something in the text box and press the button nothing appears in the listbox

Comment: I updated the close last night and tested it in visual studio. I had originally put Select instead of Where. But what I have there works. .Contains is a string method so it should be showing up unless there is something wrong with how you typed the code. If you post what you have I can look look at it and see.

Comment: Also, make sure that you are using .Where on the List<string> and not the ListBox. Messages and messages are not the same thing. Messages is a ListBox and messages is a List<string> that the ListBox ItemsSource is set to.

Comment: I finally got it to work but the problem I now have is that if I add an item it goes into the list box, then I do a search and it works but after I’ve done a search, if I go to add another item to the listbox I have to press the search button to update the listbox

Comment: I would need to see how you have everything setup. How are you submitting new items to the ListBox? Are you using a textbox and a button to add new items? Did you put the code for the search in a button click or in the TextBoxChanged event? If you can post some more code, that would be helpful. Then I can be of more help.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the item source as a CollectionViewSource object,  set source of the object is the string array, then and a filter for the object, you can filter the element in the filter function